# Android - RelativeLayout w/RecyclerView and Anchored Button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

First, I appreciate any help I may get on this issue as it's left me scratching my head a little over the past two days.

I have a RelativeLayout wrapping a Button and a RecyclerView, with the Button aligned to the parent's bottom and the RecyclerView aligned to the parent's top (along with above the Button). Hence, I am attempting to anchor the button at the bottom of the screen at all times and have the RecyclerView above it (there will only ever be a max of 3 items in the RecyclerView as the optimal options for the user).

When I do this, the Button is always appearing as expected at the bottom of the page. However, the button never fires the click event, which is a real head scratcher for me. Here's the really odd part, if I replace the RecyclerView with just a TextView (just for testing the button), the click event is fired. Then I can put the RecyclerView back in and the click event is not fired again. I have this concept of an anchored button within a RelativeLayout working in multiple other locations in the app, but this one (the only with a RecyclerView) is giving me problems.

I am targeting SDK Version 23 and using all build tools and support libraries at version 23.X.

Just as an FYI, the root element of this fragment, and the only other view on the fragment at this time, is a FrameLayout. If I don't need to layer anymore buttons on the fragment (e.g. FloatingActionButton) once this portion of the app is completed, then I'll make the RelativeLayout the root layout of the fragment at that time.

```
<-- Options Container -->
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/container"
              android:gravity="top"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" >

    <!-- More Options Button -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/more_options"
            android:padding="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/more_options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <!-- List of Optimal Options -->
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_above="@+id/more_options" >
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/optimal_options_recycler" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```